# Is it possible to define a method in a Factory Girl factory that is not in the associated Active::Record model?1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

So I have a factory:

```
factory :person do
    password_string { Faker::Lorem.words(3).join }

    after(:create) do |object|
      object.password = object.password_hash(object.password_string)
      object.save!
    end   
end
```

And I get an error:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `password_string=' for #<Person:0xe1cdf00>
```

Which is expected, but I want to define the password_string for my test environment (mainly so I can mock a signed in user). Is there a way to get around the NoMethodError by defining attributes that are unique to the factory?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can! Usually you'd put these on a trait, not certain if you can put them on a plain factory or not.

```
trait :with_password_string do
  ignore do
    password_string nil
  end

  after(:build) do |content, evaluator|
    if evaluator.password_string
      content.password = content.password_hash(evaluator.password_string)
    end
  end
end
```